# C# subscribing delegates stored in a dictionary to an event

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm working in C# on a system which saves an anonymous delegate to a dictionary (allowing me to unbind it later) and binding it to an event:

```
public static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<List<string>,Action>> boundActions;
public delegate void EventListener();
public Dictionary<int,EventListener> listenerMap;


public void bindListener(int actionID, List<string> actionArgs, int listenerID)
{
        boundActions[actionID][actionArgs]=delegate(){actions.getAction(actionID, actionArgs).Invoke ();};
        listenerMap[listenerID]+=boundActions[actionID][actionArgs];
        
}

public void unbindListener(int actionID, List<string> actionArgs, int listenerID)
{
        listenerMap[listenerID]-=boundActions[actionID][actionArgs];
        
}
```

However, this approach doesn't compile, giving me the following errors:

> error CS0019: Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type
> `ItemListeners.EventListener` and `System.Action`
>
> error CS0019: Operator '-=' cannot be applied to operands of type
> `ItemListeners.EventListener` and `System.Action`

Am I approaching the problem incorrectly? Is there a better approach to this, or is there a way I can make it work this way? Maybe the type `Action` is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to duplicate the action in a second dictionary in the first place?  You already have exactly the same data in the first dictionary.  The fact that you're mysteriously using two types of delegates when you should only be using one is irrelevant when you shouldn't be using the delegate in more than one place to begin with.

Comment: I have specifically split up events I want to use as "listeners" and events I want to use as "actions", so that I can bind an action to a listener - keeping the already bound actions is simply a means to an end for allowing unbinding.

Comment: But the two aren't any different.  They're the same thing.  Rather than keeping a list of integers to read from an a list of integers to write to (in which writing to that one modifies the other list), you just have one list that you read and write from.  In the same light here, you just need to have a lookup of actions, and invoke those actions as appropriate.  Duplicating the lookup accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Why do you insist on using two different types of a delegate for the same thing? Just pick one and stick with it.

Comment: I'm sure what you guys are saying makes perfect sense but I'm struggling to understand. Could you illustrate with an example?

Comment: Unanswerable because we can't fathom the use of the `delegate(){...}` part. Try to make a minimal mockup that is complete.

Answer (score -1):

check this

```
public static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<List<string>, EventListener>> boundActions;
public delegate void EventListener();
public Dictionary<int, EventListener> listenerMap;

public void bindListener(int actionID, List<string> actionArgs, int listenerID)
{
    boundActions[actionID][actionArgs] = new EventListener(delegate { actions.getAction(actionID, actionArgs).Invoke(); });
    listenerMap[listenerID] += boundActions[actionID][actionArgs];
}

public void unbindListener(int actionID, List<string> actionArgs, int listenerID)
{
    listenerMap[listenerID] -= boundActions[actionID][actionArgs];
}
```

Comment: The action you're removing won't ever be equal to the action you're adding.

Comment: Replacing `<..., Action>` with `<..., EventListener>` is a partial answer. It addresses the (only) error in the question. It does not result in working code though.